# MySql Query omitting the last recorded row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

My MYSQL query works fine extept for one thing... It omits the last recorded row in my table. Take a look at my code;

```
$Articlesql3 = "SELECT * FROM Group WHERE Group_ID = '$id' ORDER BY ID DESC";
$Articlequery3 = mysqli_query($connection, $Articlesql3);
$Articlerow3 = mysqli_fetch_object($Articlequery3);

while($Articlerow3 = mysqli_fetch_object($Articlequery3)){
      $Articleid3 = $Articlerow3->Article_ID;
      $Articlesql4 = "SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE Article_ID = '$Articleid3'";
$Articlequery4 = mysqli_query($connection, $Articlesql4);
while($Articlerow4 = mysqli_fetch_object($Articlequery4)){
 echo "<p><a href='ArticleReader.php?ID=$Articlerow4->Article_ID&id=$id'></i> $Articlerow4->Article_Name</a></p>";}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove this line:

```
$Articlerow3 = mysqli_fetch_object($Articlequery3);
```

You are fetching the results.  And then fetching the results again in the `while`.

The last is missing because of the `order by id desc`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
$Articlerow3 = mysqli_fetch_object($Articlequery3);
```

before the while loop.